# How can you get the serverinfo in your second args?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have a serverinfo command that shows your server info but I would like to get also other servers info by using the server id in your 2nd args. But it shows only mine and even if I have a 2nd args it does the same.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {


  var Guild = message.guild + bot.guilds.get(args[1])
  var Myguild = message.guild;

  if (!args[1] == null)

    message.channel.send("Invallid")


  var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("#c59c16")
    .setAuthor(Myguild.name, Myguild.iconURL || Guild.name, Guild.iconURL)
    .setThumbnail(Myguild.iconURL || Guild.iconURL)
    .addField("Name", Myguild.name || Guild.name, true)
    .addField("Owner", Myguild.owner || Guild.owner, true)
    .addField("Region", Myguild.region || Guild.region, true)
    .addField("ID", Myguild.id || Guild.id, true)
    .addField("Members", Myguild.memberCount || Guild.memberCount, true)
    .addField("Bots", Myguild.members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size || Guild.members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size, true)
    .addField("Voice channels", Myguild.channels.filter(chan => chan.type === 'voice').size || Guild.channels.filter(chan => chan.type === 'voice').size, true)
    .addField("Text channels", Myguild.channels.filter(chan => chan.type === 'text').size || Guild.channels.filter(chan => chan.type === 'text').size, true)
    .addField("Roles", Myguild.roles.map(r => r.name).join(" , ") || Guild.roles.map(r => r.name).join(" , "))
    .setFooter("Created: " + Myguild.createdAt || Guild.createdAt)
  message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
}


module.exports.help = {
  name: "serverinfo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you're using the `+` operator instead of `||` operator, your `Guild` variable needs to be replaced with `var Guild = message.guild || bot.guilds.get(args[1])`

Comment: It now says --> (node:15404) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body 
embed.author.icon_url: Not a well formed URL.

Comment: Because you need to use `Myguild.iconURL()`

Comment: If my answer has solved the issue you mentioned in the question, then accept it to let others know what worked

Comment: .setAuthor(Myguild.name, Myguild.iconURL() || Guild.name, Guild.iconURL())
.setThumbnail(Myguild.iconURL() || Guild.iconURL()) I add a () to iconURL but it now says that it's not a function

Comment: Oh my bad sorry, I just woke up, `Myguild.iconURL` is right but it says it's not a well formed URL, that's caused by the fact you tried using the `Guild.name` as a URL value, you need to remove `Guild.name +` leave it as `Myguild.iconURL || Guild.iconURL`

Comment: It now only works in the server I currently am and By server name it's null because I deleted the .name. So what I want is if I use the command $serverinfo it shows the server info where I am now but I want also to do $serverinfo id that shows the server info of that id I have written in the first args.